# Is there a way to test events from the test fixture directly without using expectEvents?

Tags: axon

Im trying to test an Aggregate and would like to assert the events outside of the fixture and perhaps even use Hamcrest to evaluate?

An example of using timestamps

```
        fixture.given()
           .when(new UserCreateCommand("1","test@bob.com"))
           .expectEvents(new UserCreatedEvent("1","test@bob.com");
```

The fixture allows me to easily test equality, e.g. the command produces exactly this event, its not so easy if I wanted to say introduce a Timestamp of when the event was created for example

```
        fixture.given()
           .when(new UserCreateCommand("1","test@bob.com"))
           .expectEvents(new UserCreatedEvent("1","test@bob.com", LocalDateTime.now());
```

This expectation will never work as the LocalDateTime.now() will never be precisely equal to the timestamp generated in the aggregate.

I could simply include the Timestamp in the command payload, but feel a preference to handle inside the Aggregate to ensure a consistent way of generating this timestamps.

Is there a way to retrieve the Event out of the fixture to assert independently of the fixture e.g.

```
   UserCreatedEvent uce = fixture.given()
           .when(new UserCreateCommand("1","test@bob.com"))
           .extractEvent(UserCreatedEvent.class)
```

This would then allow me to use other assertion libraries also like hamcrest for example:

e.g.

```
   assertThat(uce.getCreatedAt(), is(greaterThanOrEqualto(LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reasonable question @vcetinick!

You should actually be able to use matchers with Axon's Aggregate Test Fixtures really. The result validation part of the `AggregateTestFixture` provides the `expectEventsMatching(Matcher<? extends List<? super EventMessage<?>>> matcher)` method. You can find the code for this [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/9d6bc585f5b982436991b1b6f6e5c32cebf0b25d/test/src/main/java/org/axonframework/test/aggregate/ResultValidator.java#L87) by the way.

On top of this Axon Framework provides a set of reasonable matchers you can use for messages in general, grouped under the utility class `Matchers` (which you can find [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/test/src/main/java/org/axonframework/test/matchers/Matchers.java)).

With all this in place, you should be able to do something like this:

```java
@Test
void sampleTest() {
    FixtureConfiguration<SampleAggregate> fixture = 
        new AggregateTestFixture<>(SampleAggregate.class);
    fixture.givenNoPriorActivity()
           .when(new UserCreateCommand("1","test@bob.com"))
           .expectEventsMatching(
                   Matchers.exactSequenceOf(
                           Matchers.messageWithPayload(
                                   Matchers.matches(payload -> {
                                       // Your UserCreatedEvent validation 
                                       //  disregarding the time stamp here
                                   })
                           )
                   )
           );
}
```

You can essentially pair any number of `Matchers` methods in their if you desire.

Hoping this answers your question @vcetinick!

Answer (score 1):

Despite being an old post, for those stumbling upon the same issue, an alternative approach can be used by using

```
fixture = new AggregateTestFixture<>(YourAggregate.class);    
fixture.registerFieldFilter(new IgnoreField(YourEvent.class, "date"));
```

In this example, `YourEvent` could be an event implementation class of a base class for all events containing a timestamp field `date`.

```
@NotNull(message = "The event date cannot be null")
@Past(message = "The event date cannot be in the future")
@JsonProperty(value = EVENT_DATE_TAG, required = true)
private ZonedDateTime date;
```

Using this approach, all calls to `expectXXXX` test-methods ignore the `date` field.